# Как передать массив на страницу?

Tags: php

Как можно передать массив $orderlist на страницу success.php

````
$i=1;
foreach($orderlist as $id => $item_data) {
    $total_sum += (float)$item_data['count'] * (float)$item_data['price'];
    $tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['id'].'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333;"><img src="'.$item_data['img'].'" alt="" style="max-width: 64px; max-height: 64px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['title'].'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['price'].'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['count'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}```
````

Comment: у тебя таблица а массив просто в сессию запихни, и на любой странице воспроизведи

Comment: @Bloom подскажите как это сделать

Comment: яж не знаю что именно тебе надо, может с сессиями плохая идея) сессия php, а так вот http://lphp.ru/article/393.html

Comment: @Bloom мне нужно передать массив с данными на страницу success.php, так как я передаю name и phone , только целый массив

Comment: значит сессию используй

Comment: посмотри вначале массив print_r($orderlist); если он вложенный ; то по тем ключам $orderlist[0]['name'];

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100236/discussion-between-alexander-and-bloom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для начала создайте сессию

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['arr']=$orderlist;

// на принемающей стороне
 session_start(); 
$sendorder=$_SESSION['arr'];
print_r($sendorder['id']);
```